# Radiobutton functionality in a android

Tags: android

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_individualdays"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_type_of_days"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/BreakfastRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Mon"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/LunchRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Tue"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Wed"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/BreakfastRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Thu"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/LunchRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Fri"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Sat"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Sun"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
```

- **Now the output is** ::

[image]

- **If i select another option including others say "tue"**, the option "wed" deselects itself

[image]

---

- **But i want to be able to select all if required**

[image]

- **None if required**

[image]

---

*How to resolve this*, Hope i am clear

Comment: Try to use `Checkbox` instead of `RadioButton`.

Comment: Well, that is radio button usecase. like @Gunaseelan mentioned... you can use checkboxes.. Or you can just use different radio groups and manage each radio button yourself.

Comment: How to use the checkbox ..... i see only radio button option in eclipse module selection ..... correct me if im wrong .... im new to android ... can you show a sample ...say for example for just 2 check box

Comment: use checkbox instead of Radiobutton, here also you can get ischecked properties

Comment: this may helps you http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="checkBox1" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="checkBox2"
    android:checked="true" /> 

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Check" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private checkBox1,checkBox2;
private Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        result.append("checkBox1 : ").append(checkBox1.isChecked());
        result.append("checkBox2 : ").append(checkBox2.isChecked());

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  }
});

 }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the layout as follows :

None of the Radio buttons will be selected at launch, but you can select them individually.

You just had to put them outside RadioGroup.

But You won't be able to de-select those Radio buttons, if selected mistakenly.

Checkboxes are a Proper way to go for such a thing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Radiobutton in wikipedia says

> A **RadioButton** or option button is a type of graphical user interface
>   element that allows the user to choose only **one** of a predefined set of options.

You would have to just use checkboxes instead of radio button for allowing multiple options to be selected,else you are doing something which is inherently wrong in a UI be it mobile/web.

If still want to use RadioButtons, don't put them all in a RadioGroup. Either put them in several groups or manage them yourself completely.

Comment: This a copy paste I guess.. anyways.. +1 for the effort

Comment: yes it is. Mixed up the best answers. But it will solve his issue :)